# Form is not submitting in node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to make a post request from a html form and cant figure out where im going wrong.

```
>         <form action="/api" method="POST">
            <label for="username">username or email address</label>
            <input name="username" id="username" type="text">
            <label for="password">password</label>
            <input id="password"name="password" type="text">
            <button >Log in</button>
        </form>
```

here is my main javascript file for the html (not the server)

```
    "use strict"

let options = {
    headers:{
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    },
    method: "POST",
}
// fetch("/api",options)
```

And here is my node js server

```
"use strict"

//Installing express
let express = require(`express`)
let app = express()
app.use(express.json())

//running the server
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("server is running boi");
})
//Middleware to load the static content
app.use(express.static(`public`))

//Database stuff 
let Datastore = require('nedb')
let db = new Datastore({ filename: 'database.db' });
db.loadDatabase()
db.insert({username:"sid", password:"westham"})

//Handler for any post requests made
app.post(`/api`,(req,res)=>{
    console.log("request was made");
    console.log(req.body);
    
})
```

Comment: you used `backticks` sign instead you need to use either single or double quotes in `post` request that may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two Observations

> No `middleware` found in your `server.js` file for handling form data,
> use `body-parser` http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
```

> In your html form, if you're not submitting form with JavaScript then mentiod button type as `submit`

```
<button type="submit" >Log in</button>
```